# Having trouble with Multiple Selection in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been trying to selection of cell like

### Same As Checkbox To select elements from object array

Here is my code. Please guide me.. Thanks in advance

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CheckAllListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *_myTable;
    NSMutableArray *_myArray;
    NSMutableArray *_selectedArray;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *myTable;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *myArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *selectedArray;
-(void)checkmarkAll;
-(void)UnChceckAll;
```

### CheckAllListViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Check All",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10" ,nil];
    _selectedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

#pragma mark -UITableViewDelegates & Datasource

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedArray addObject:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        //if 'all' row is selected then check all rows
        if([[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Check All"]) 
        {
            [self checkmarkAll];
        }
    } 
    else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedArray removeObject:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        if([[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Check All"]) 
        {
            [self UnChceckAll];
            [self.selectedArray removeAllObjects];
        }
        else if([self.selectedArray containsObject:@"Check All"]) 
        {
            [self checkmarkAll];
            [self.selectedArray removeAllObjects];

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [self.selectedArray addObject:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if([self.selectedArray count]) 
    {

        if([self.selectedArray containsObject:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] || [self.selectedArray containsObject:@"Check All"]) 
        {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } 
        else 
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _myArray.count;
}

-(void)checkmarkAll
{
    for (int i=0;i<[self.myArray count] ; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *myIdx=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell=[self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIdx];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}

-(void)UnChceckAll
{
    for(int i=0;i<[self.myArray count];i++) 
    {

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

I've used this tutorial -http://iphonediscoveries.blogspot.in/2013/10/creating-inclusive-list-in-uitableview.html

I want to achieve :
 1 Add an option for the user to be able to select all rows when ‘all’ is selected.

2 When the ‘all’ is checked I want all rows checkmarked, and all checkmarks removed when 'all' is unchecked.

3  When ‘all’ is checked, and all rows are checkmarked, if at that time a row is clicked, then check marks in all other rows should be removed (including ‘all’) and only that row should contain the checkmark.
4  Should not forget Selection After calling and scrolling UITableview

### UPDATE

**-My Following code gives me check all functionality & Uncheck All Functionality .
Lets say I've chosen all row by selecting check all now,If I'd choose any row randomly Should remove tick from current selected element & as well should remove tick from first element i.e @"Check All"** 
-same for uncheck functionality

Comment: You might want to update your answer to explain what your current code does.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get what the problem is, but I would change the checkAll and uncheckAll methods to change the selectedArray and reload the tableview:

```
-(void)checkmarkAll
{
    self.selectedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.myArray];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```